# flutter integration test how to tap on camera button

Tags: flutter

In flutter integration test, if we want to tap on a button that is built by ourselves, we can easily do it by:

```
await driver.tap(find.byValueKey("my_lovely_button_key"));
```

However, if a widget is not built by us, for example, a date picker, an image picker, etc., how do we tap on any of the buttons there?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Tried [Find a specific widget instance](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/finders#3-find-a-specific-widget-instance) from the flutter docs?

Comment: But we still don't know what widget to look for right?

Comment: Right, in cases like custom Button or similar we wont have details about the widget.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have to open a camera at all in your tests. It can be skipped and have `image_picker` lib return you some image immediately after opening camera following this answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588555/how-to-test-imagepicker-in-flutter-driver

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the date picker, what I found to be useful is that you can click on any button using:

```
await driver.tap(find.text('btn_name'));
```

For example, if you need the date `11 June 2020`, you need to do these steps:

1. ```
   await driver.tap(find.text('11'));
   ```
2. ```
   await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
   ```
3. ```
   await driver.tap(find.text('OK'));
   ```

What these steps will do is:

1. Tap on button which has a text of "11",
2. Wait for 1 second, and then
3. Tap on the "OK" button.