# Flutter Test Driver: Tap on Camera Button in Android Emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator

I am running some tests on my Flutter application, and I need a way to Tap on the Camera button to be able to take a picture, and then Tap on the Check Button (shown below) to validate it. I need a way to find the coordinates to tap on the location of the 2 buttons, or use `await driver.tap(find.byValueKey('Key'));` by adding a testKey to the camera button's widget. I am not sure if `driver.tap()` can be used to tap anywhere on the screen.

These are the two screenshots:

| Camera Button | Check Button |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're probably using ImagePicker, in that case have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56623790/15212468) answer. There you can see that the author mocks the library, so you get the image without going into the camera.

Remember to add the file you want to load in pubspec.yaml and also, in my case I didn't need this line:

`enableFlutterDriverExtension();`

Comment: Thank you! 
After some research on how to solve my issue, I came across the same answer that you provided me which has solved my problem.

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct, please? @AndrewArnita