# Mocking ImagePicker in flutter integration_tests not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test, flutter-image-picker

I have tried [Flutter Image Picker integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71064033/flutter-image-picker-integration-tests) and [How to test ImagePicker in Flutter Driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588555/how-to-test-imagepicker-in-flutter-driver). I am using [ImagePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin as below:

`final result = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);`

I have tried above solution, still the image picker opens `gallery` on emulator and never returns to the app for continuing testing.

**Edit**
Below is my sample code to mock, but no handler is called.

```
mockImagePicker(WidgetTester tester){
  print("Setting mockImagePicker starts");
  const MethodChannel channel =
  MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/image_picker');

  handler(MethodCall methodCall) async {
    print("Called method in mock method call is: ${methodCall.method}");
    print("mock handler called handler");
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('images/SplashScreen.png');
    Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    File file = await File('${tempDir.path}/tmp.tmp', ).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    print(file.path);
    return file.path;
  };

  channel.setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
    print("mock handler called setMockMethodCallHandler");
    return <String, String>{
      'type': 'image',
      'path': '/example/path',
    };
  });

  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding?.instance?.defaultBinaryMessenger
      ?.setMockMethodCallHandler(channel, handler);
  tester.binding.defaultBinaryMessenger.setMockMethodCallHandler(channel, (message) async {
    print("type 2 mock image");
    return await handler(message);
  });

}
```

Can anybody help what else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Define FakeImagePicker Class and override getImageFromSource and
> getMultiImageWithOptions method: and return temp image from asset folder.

```html
class FakeImagePicker extends ImagePickerPlatform {
  @override
  Future<XFile?> getImageFromSource({
    required ImageSource source,
    ImagePickerOptions options = const ImagePickerOptions(),
  }) async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/a1.png');
    final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final File file = await File(
      '${tempDir.path}/doc.png',
    ).writeAsBytes(bytes);

    return XFile(file.path);
  }

  @override
  Future<List<XFile>> getMultiImageWithOptions({
    MultiImagePickerOptions options = const MultiImagePickerOptions(),
  }) async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/home/binoculars.png');
    final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final File file = await File(
      '${tempDir.path}/binoculars.png',
    ).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return <XFile>[
      XFile(
        file.path,
      )
    ];
  }
}
```

Then in your test set-up set  ImagePickerPlatform to FakeImagePicker

```html
setUp(() {
    ImagePickerPlatform.instance = FakeImagePicker();
  });
```

Then in your test case simply tap on image upload button it will mock that particular method:

```html
   testWidget(tester){

      await tester.tap(find.byKey(uploadKey(docType)));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
         
     }
```

> And if you are also using FilePicker library to use pick file then u
> can also mock FilePicker library and call this mockFilePicker in your test setup.

```html
  void mockFilePicker(String fileName) {
    const MethodChannel channelFilePicker =
        MethodChannel('miguelruivo.flutter.plugins.filepicker');

    TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger
        .setMockMethodCallHandler(
      channelFilePicker,
      (MethodCall methodCall) async {
        final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/home/$fileName');
        final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
        final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        final File file = await File(
          '${tempDir.path}/tmp.tmp',
        ).writeAsBytes(bytes);

        return [
          {
            'name': fileName,
            'path': file.path,
            'bytes': bytes,
            'size': bytes.lengthInBytes,
          }
        ];
      },
    );
  }
```

> I Hope this would be clear how to mock image picker from ImagePicker
> and FilePicker.

Answer (score 1):

That code assumes that `image_picker` uses a method channel called `plugins.flutter.io/image_picker`, which hasn't been true for a while. As explained in the Flutter docs, you [should not mock the internal method channels of plugins](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/plugins-in-tests), for exactly this reason. The code you are trying to use would have worked in the past, but no longer does because it is assuming internal plugin implementation details never change, which isn't the case.

As explained in that document, you should wrap your call to the plugin in something mockable, since then your code doesn't rely on internal details of a package you don't control. Failing that you could (also as explained in the docs) set a different platform implementation for the plugin (via `ImagePickerPlatform.instance`), but that is also fragile to changes in plugin implementation details.